# data conversion issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, sql-server-2014, data-conversion

I have a table in which one of field is Real data type. I need to show the values in decimal format like #.###. So i'm converting the real values to decimal. But when i convert for some values it is not generating actual value. For eg:- 20.05 is the actual value. multiple it by 100 and then it to decimal(9,4) it will return like 2004.9999.

```
select cast(cast(20.05 as real)*100.00 as decimal(9,4))
```

Why this is returning like this ?

Comment: It will return?

Comment: Show actual numbers, actual code you used, and value returned.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a style in the conversion https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_5

Comment: The actual value and its textual representation (the *format*) are two different things. In most cases, formatting is something to be done in your presentation layer. Which version of SQL-Server?

Comment: @ Shnugo i'm using sql 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Real` or `Float` are not precise...

Even if you **see** the value as "20.05", even if you type it in like this, there will be tiny differences.

Your value `2004.9999` (or similar something like `2005.00001`) is due to the internal representation of this type.

If you do the conversion to `decimal` first, it should work as expected:

```
select cast(cast(20.05 as real) as decimal(9,4))*100.00
```

But you should really think about, where and why you use floating point numbers...

### UPDATE: Format-function

With SQL-Server 2012+ you might use [`FORMAT()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(20.05 AS REAL)*100,'###.0.000')
```

This will allow you, to sepcify the format, and you will get **text** back.

This is fine for presentation output (lists, reports), but not so fine, if you want to continue with some kinds of calculations.